# CosmosDB - Invalid BSON field name 'places.$id'

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Azure CosmoDB on MongoDB document model and I face odd behavior on updating some documents using [DBRefs $id](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref-explanation)

Take look this script sample:

```
original_id = ObjectId()

db.places.insert({
    "_id": original_id,
    "name": "Broadway Center",
    "url": "bc.example.net"
})

db.people.insert({
    "name": "Erin",
    "places":{"$ref":"places","$id": original_id},
    "url":  "bc.example.net/Erin"
})

db.people.find({"places.$id": original_id}) //works like charm
db.people.update({"places.$id": original_id}, {$set:{"NEW_FIELD": false}}, {multi:true}) //doesn't works =/
```

Then return:

```
Failed to execute script.

Error: Error: error: {
    "_t" : "OKMongoResponse",
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 2,
    "errmsg" : "Invalid BSON field name 'places.$id'",
    "$err" : "Invalid BSON field name 'places.$id'"
} :
DBCollection.prototype.update@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:589:23
@(shell):1:1
```

I'm really appreciate if someone have a clue whats going on.

Comment: Don't use DBRef. You really should not be using it anywhere and it's clearly not supported by CosmosDB. I'm personally surprised ( stunned actually ) that there has not been a deprecation notice for DBRef storage. Almost nothing supports it and it was a bad idea in the first place. Use standard `ObjectId` values and [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to retrieve related data. Also try to model without related data. Or use an RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You shall replace

```
"places":{"$ref":"places","$id": original_id},
```

with

```
"places_id": original_id,
```

Comment: In fact, I'm inserting this data using spring data, I haven't ability to change how data is storaged on document. So, change $id is not a option.

Comment: change how document's schema is not a option. It was just a sample. Change the query to update to a non DBREF fields work's fine, but do not solve my problem.